# Help with PatternSequence

Tags: pattern-matching

I have a list of strings of the form

```
list = {str1, str2, strx, str3, .., str10}
```

each string contains both letters and numbers, except for `strx` which does not contain numbers. What I want to do is attach strx to the element that immediately precedes it, producing

> ```
> {str1, {str2, strx}, ..., str10}
> ```

I am using

```
 list /. 
   {bef___, PatternSequence[x_, m_] /; StringFreeQ[m, DigitCharacter], aft___} :> 
     {bef, {x, m}, aft}
```

However this seems to match only the first occurrence of the pattern I'm looking for. How can I make it match several cases? I also want to be able to process a list that does not contain any of the strx.

Comment: Can there be *strx*s in sequence, e.g. `{...,strn,strx,strx,strn...}`? Can there be a *strx* at the start of the list, and if so, what is to be done? You need to specify your problem much more precisely.

Comment: Good catch, no, the strx do not follow each other.

Comment: Well, actually i found out that there are some cases in which up to 3 strx follow a single stri. In that case, I would like to attach each of those strx to the stri that immediately precedes it: `{str1, strx1, srtx2, strx3, str2}` should result in `{{str1, strx1, strx2, strx3}, str2}`

Comment: Oh, and no, an strx will never be at the beginning.

Comment: It is *seriously* uncool to fundamentally change the objective, particularly after already answering a question about the change oppositely.

Answer (score 7):

Here is one way:

```
lines={"123","312","anb","452","Xys"}

ReleaseHold[
 lines //. {bef___, 
    PatternSequence[x_String, 
     m_String?(StringFreeQ[#, DigitCharacter] &)], 
    aft___} :> {bef, {Hold[x], m}, aft}]

(* ==> {"123", {"312", "anb"}, {"452", "Xys"}} *)
```

I changed the pattern so that it tests the `Head` of `x` and `m` as well, and wrap `x` in `Hold` in the replacement. That way, when I then do `ReplaceRepeated`, the `Hold` will prevent an infinite recursion.

**Edit: simplicity and speed**

If you don't insist on using `PatternSequence`, I would strongly recommend doing it this way:

```
lines = {"123", "127", "312", "anb", "45h2", "Xys"}

Split[lines, StringFreeQ[#2, DigitCharacter] &] /. {x_} :> x

(* ==> {"123", "127", {"312", "anb"}, {"45h2", "Xys"}} *)
```

This uses the second argument of [`Split`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html) to test the *subsequent* element for every list member and checks that it satisfies the condition. Then it groups the two elements surrounding the position where this result changes into a list.

Comment: Interesting idea, but performance is.... interesting. Lists with no elements with no digits are done reasonably fast. Adding just one element with that condition clobbers performance, adding many....things get ugly...

Comment: @ciao Well, the question was about `PatternSequence`...

Comment: @ciao I added an alternative solution that is also "interesting".

Comment: Second is pretty sweet, appears to be second fastest so far. +1 on that.

Comment: @ciao Are you sure you want to delete your A? It can still teach readers a lot. Anyway, luckily my second approach still seems to work for the modified Q, too.

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting tired of anserine moving goalpost questions. You can about triple the speed of yours, but OP has not specified list sizes, probably moot.

Answer (score 4):

An approach using `ReplaceRepeated` and a temporary tag.

```
data = 
  {"DD1", "B12", "CCC", "3AD", "C2A", "3D1", "1A1", "C11", "BBA", 
   "322", "1D2", "B3C", "1BD", "CC1", "AC"};

list //. 
  {bef___, 
   PatternSequence[x_, m_] /; Head[m] =!= tag && StringFreeQ[m, DigitCharacter], 
   aft___} :> {bef, tag[x, m], aft} /. 
     tag -> List
```

> ```
> {"DD1", {"B12", "CCC"}, "3AD", "C2A", "3D1", "1A1", {"C11", "BBA"}, 
>  "322", "1D2", "B3C", "1BD", {"CC1", "AC"}}
> ```

Comment: You must have posted this after I left - it's similar to what I did, but nonetheless an independent solution (+1).

Answer (score 2):

One option is to apply the rule over and over again until it doesn't have any effect:

```
list = {"DD1", "B12", "CCC", "3AD", "C2A", "3D1", "1A1", "C11", "BBA",
    "322", "1D2", "B3C", "1BD", "CC1", "AC"};

FixedPoint[Replace[#, {
     bef___,
     PatternSequence[x_, m_] /; StringFreeQ[m, DigitCharacter],
     aft___
     } :> {bef, {x, m}, aft}] &,
 list
 ]

(* Out: {"DD1", {"B12", "CCC"}, "3AD", "C2A", "3D1", "1A1", {"C11", 
  "BBA"}, "322", "1D2", "B3C", "1BD", {"CC1", "AC"}} *)
```

You may also consider this approach to solving your problem:

```
replacePair[{str1_, str2_}] := Module[{freeQ1, freeQ2},
  freeQ1 = StringFreeQ[str1, DigitCharacter];
  freeQ2 = StringFreeQ[str2, DigitCharacter];
  If[freeQ1, ## &[], If[freeQ2, {str1, str2}, str1]]
  ]
replacePair[{str_}] := If[StringFreeQ[str, DigitCharacter], ## &[], str]

Developer`PartitionMap[replacePair, list, 2, 1, {1, 1}, {}]

(* Out: {"DD1", {"B12", "CCC"}, "3AD", "C2A", "3D1", "1A1", {"C11", 
  "BBA"}, "322", "1D2", "B3C", "1BD", {"CC1", "AC"}} *)
```

Comment: Wouldn't `//.` be appropriate here?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Jens showed how to do that, the reason I used `Replace` instead is because it only works on the top level so I don't have to do the `Hold`/`ReleaseHold` trick.